# ClickOnce Source Controlled Files

Tags: c#, svn, version-control, clickonce, publish

I'm using the ClickOnce publishing feature with Visual C# 2008 and a WinForm application.  I have been using Subversion to handle my source control for this app, and was wondering which of the ClickOnce generated files in the project directory I need to add to source control and which should be ignored like user files...?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know published files need not to be added to source control just like assemblies they are generated files which source control has nothing to do with

Comment: In the published directory, yes, I agree.  But what about the ones in the project directory?  app.config, app.manifest, etc.?

Comment: Yes project directory files must be added, both app.config and app.manifest
If you used team foundation server, all these files would be added automatically
On the other hand you should note that all files required to create the same assembly and functionality as in your machine must be added to create same assembly and functionality in another machine

Comment: I just want to be clear, do you know this for a fact?  Because not all project directory files should be added to source control.  I want to make sure I'm not checking-in user settings...